# React.useEffect doesn't re-render on axios interception

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

`http://localhost:5000/posts` retrieves a list of posts. I call this in useEffect and I can render this correctly. If, however, my token has expired I have to intercept and refresh this token, and then re-send the request. `axios_server.interceptors.response.use` does this, but it does not trigger the `setTest(res.data)` and even though the new request is made, the data is not saved in the state. How can I solve this, and what is the prudent way to go about this?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    axios_server.get('http://localhost:5000/posts', {withCredentials: true}).then((res) => {
      console.log('res.data: ', res.data)
      setTest(res.data)
    })
  }, [])
```

```
axios_server.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {

    // We got 401, refresh token
    if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        axios_auth.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh', {}, {withCredentials: true}).then((res) => {

            // status ok, set access token in cookie and run last request again
            let token = res.data['accessToken']
            cookies.set('AccessToken', token, {sameSite: 'strict', path:'/', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3 * 1000)})
            return axios_server.request(error.config)

        }, (error2) => {
        
            // refresh token got 401
            return Promise.reject(error)
        
        })
      
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios_auth.post` was missing a return

```
axios_server.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {

    // We got 401, refresh token
    if (error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        return axios_auth.post('http://localhost:4000/refresh', {}, {withCredentials: true}).then((res) => {

            // status ok, set access token in cookie and run last request again
            let token = res.data['accessToken']
            cookies.set('AccessToken', token, {sameSite: 'strict', path:'/', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3 * 1000)})
            return axios_server.request(error.config)

        }, (error2) => {
        
            // refresh token got 401
            return Promise.reject(error)
        
        })
      
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Data not refreshing page (though I can see the API call get made and includes it). What is `axios_auth` ? You reference it, but don't have it defined in the code above.